# MongoDBReceiver failing Authentication

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

[image: Blockquote]

I'm receiving the error above. It looks like the collector is trying to authenticate to the mongo instance using SCRAM-SHA-1.

[image]

The above is what I have in my OpenTelemetry collector config. I'm providing the plaintext versions of the username and password, which works if I logged into mongo using a tool like mongodb compass but only if authentication mechanism is set to Default.

How do I make the OpenTelemetry collector authenticate using Default instead of SCRAM-SHA-1? I think I could also make my password conform to SCRAM-SHA-1 but I hadn't been able to make that work either.

A couple of notes that might be helpful:
*MongoDb instance is in a docker container
*OpenTelemetry collector is running as a process in my host system

Answer (score 0):

The authentication mechanism is not configurable. Please consider opening a feature request [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/new/choose).